# Does the node.js express framework create a new lightweight process per client connection?

Tags: node.js, express

Say this code is run inside of a node.js express application. Say two different clients request the index resource. Call these clients ClientA and ClientB. Say ClientA requests the index resource before ClientB. In this case the console will log the value 1 for ClientA and the console will log the value 2 for ClientB. My main question is: Does each client request get its own lightweight process with the router being the shared code portion between those processes, the variables visible to router but not part of the router being the shared heap and of course each client then gets their own stack? My sub questions is: If yes to my main question then in this example each of these clients would have to queue waiting for the lock the global_counter before incrementing,correct?

```
var global_counter = 0;

router.get('/', function (req, res) {

    global_counter += 1;

    console.log(global_counter);        

    res.render('index');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Single thread/process.  Concurrency is accomplished via a work queue.  Some ways to get stuff into the work queue include setTimeout() and nexttick().  Check out http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Only one thing is running at a time, so no need to do any locking.

It takes a while to get your brain to warm up to the idea.

Comment: This answer makes sense and I think this is correct. It was also enlightening because now I'm a little more nervous about CPU intensive tasks with node than I was before. I suppose if a task is really CPU intensive you'd just send it off as io to another process or a cloud though.

Comment: That's mostly correct.  If you have a CPU-intensive task, and you want to complete it with JavaScript, split it into small parts that are executed asynchronously.  Or hand it off to another process, as you suggested.  No need to be nervous either way.

Comment: When there is kernel io, is there a lightweight process created in libuv that gets put onto the work queue when the io is done? I feel like the stack as it is before the io call must be preserved for a client somehow.

Comment: Sorry -- I don't know that.  But I think that instead of thinking in terms of stack frames, you should be thinking in terms of "closures."  Closures include "the environment," but I don't know how that's implemented.